# Send a piece of Information with every Breeze API Call

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, breeze

I wish to send a piece of information with **every Breeze API call** after authentication from **Auth0**. For example: I have this end point in **BreezeController** name as **Tasks** (with parameter, Id), which pulls all the Tasks referenced by that Id. Now I wish some information to be **sent by default with these API calls**, for example, I may want to send Name, Location, Latitude, Longitude **without mentioning them in the current API call** i.e. Tasks, so that I can retrieve them at the end point(Tasks, server side).

Or take it this way I may want to send the **Id of the user** by default with each call i.e. end point may not have Id as parameter but end point is able to retrieve sent id by some mechanism.

I don't want them to be sent in this manner:

```
EntityQuery.from('Tasks').withParameters({ Latitude: someLatitude });
```

Is there any way through which I can achieve this? I hope I have made my point clear.

Answer (score 0):

OK guys, I have found out the answer myself. I needed to send Request Header along with every Breeze call.

So I set my header at client side using:

```
var ajaxAdapter = breeze.config.getAdapterInstance('ajax');
ajaxAdapter.defaultSettings = { headers: { "userId": userId} }; //where userId is some string
```

Then in `ApiController` I retrieved this header by calling:

```
IEnumerable<string> header;
var userId = string.Empty;
if (Request.Headers.TryGetValues("userId", out header))
    userId= header.FirstOrDefault();
```

Thanks everyone